# Passing js variables to php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to do a realllly simple post of a javascript variable to a php file.

Jquery bit in keyinput.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var imgArray = [<?php echo implode(',', getImages($cat, $site)) ?>];
$(document).ready(function() {      

    var img = document.getElementById("showimg");
    img.src = imgArray[<?php echo $imgid ?>];
    var imgIndex = <?php echo $imgid ?>;

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        int rightarrow = 39;
        int leftarrow = 37;
        int random = 82;

        if (key != rightarrow && key != leftarrow && key != random) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            //next image: right arrow
            if (key == rightarrow) 
            {
                imgIndex++;
                if (imgIndex > imgArray.length-1) 
                {
                    imgIndex = 0;
                }
                img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
            }
            //last image: left arrow
            if (key == leftarrow) 
            {
                if (imgIndex == 0) 
                {
                    imgIndex = imgArray.length;
                }
                img.src = imgArray[--imgIndex];
            }
            //random: r
            if (key == random) 
            {
                imgIndex = Math.floor((Math.random()*(imgArray.length-1))+1);
                img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
            }   
        }
        $.post('./templates/viewcomic.php', {variable: imgIndex});
    });
});

</script>
<?php
function  getImages($catParam, $siteParam) {
include './scripts/dbconnect.php';

if ($siteParam == 'artwork') { 
    $table = "artwork"; 
}       
else { 
    $table = "comics"; 
}   

if ($catParam != null) {
    $catResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, title, path, thumb, catidFK FROM $table WHERE catidFK = $catParam");
}
else {
    $catResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, title, path, thumb, catidFK FROM $table");
}

$img = array();
while($row = $catResult->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $img[] = "'" . $row['path'] . "'";
}
return $img;
}
?>
```

PHP bit in viewcomic.php:

```
include './scripts/keyinput.php'; 

$JSIndex = $_POST['variable'];
echo "Index = " . $JSIndex;
//$JSIndex should be equal to the javascript variable imgIndex... but it outputs nothing
```

Any thoughts would be extremely helpful! I'm trying to get my comics website to go live.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you expect to see the output? You are doing an AJAX post, and you have no `success` handler in the `$.post()`.  Look in your browser's network console to see the response.

Comment: Have you tried putting single quotes around your var like `var imgIndex = '<?php echo $imgid ?>';`

Comment: For debugging purposes, it's better to do `var_dump($_POST);` and inspect the results in the network console of your browser.

Comment: @Jack yeah I tried that. It says "array  empty"

Comment: Is your included keyinput.php destroying / manipulating the `$_POST` superglobal? Your code looks correct to me.

Comment: @DavidMüller I don't think so... I've added the entire keyinput.php code above

Comment: But there has to be someting else going on this page, otherwise getImages, $cat, $site, $imgid ... wouldn't have been defined, would they?

Comment: @DavidMüller True, I added my getImages function which is in the viewcomic.php file... keyinput.php calls this

Comment: Hm, don't see a problem there. What is your chrome web inspector saying?

Comment: one problem is you are making an ajax call for every key pressed anywhere on page. There is no flag set to not send if keys other than the ones you want are used

Comment: @charlietfl that's a good point... how can I make that initial check? And what would that have to do with posting a javascript variable to a php file? (just curious)

Comment: store `e.which in variable` , extra if to check that it is one of the 3 you want. just do `return` if it isn't and the rest of the code won;t be run

Comment: @charlietfl I made edits to the above javascript. Now the image isn't showing at all :/

Comment: Could you check the network console in your browser and take note of the request headers of your `$.post()` call.

Comment: @Jack are you referring to the fact that I'm posting to a php file that I'm already being executed from? (the javascript file is being included from within viewcomic.php... then I'm posting back to viewcomic.php)

Comment: Stick this thing on a *fiddle site (http://phpfiddle.org/ ?) so we don't have this nightmarish debug-via-internet-comments scenario.

Comment: @BenGraham Good idea, but I think it'd be hard to do because I have several php files that all interact with each other, plus database interaction.

Comment: Usually the exercise of getting the problem isolated and repeatable in a single fiddle is what gets you to solve it, rather than other people being able to look at it. If you get it isolated and still can't figure it out, _then_ you need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong: at the moment you define your `key` variable, `e` is undefined. Then you attach your event handler inside an `if` statement that will always evaluate to false so that will never work.

The assignment to `key` should be inside your event handler and the conditional needs to go, you already have that inside your event handler.

**Edit:** you should also only do your ajax call if one of your action keys is pressed (put it inside the event handler) and do something with the result.

**Edit 2:** Checkout the manual on [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), you should add a callback function to process the return value of your php script.

For example:

```
$.post(
       './templates/viewcomic.php',
       { variable: imgIndex },
       function(data) {    /* data contains what you have echoed out in your php script */
           alert(data);
       }
      );
```

Comment: oops oops I didn't mean to write it like that, lemme fix

Comment: @Growler You are still not using the return value of your ajax function.

Comment: can you please explain? I thought I could do a simple $.post("php file I want to call", {variable: imgIndex}) and capture that imgIndex javascript value in the php file

Comment: I've tried that. "data" ends up containing all of the html for the php file. But data should contain the javascript value I want

Comment: @Growler Then you should make sure that your script only outputs the javascript value you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19536/discussion-between-growler-and-jeroen)